# os.path.join generates 4 backslashes per folder

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, append, os.path

I'm trying to write a function that finds the first instance of a particular file in the current directory and its subfolders, and returns the relative path as a string.

```
def findFirstMatch(targetFile):
    try:
        fileMatched = []
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, targetFile):
                fileMatched.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            if len(fileMatched) != 0:
                fileMatched = str(fileMatched)
                return fileMatched
        if len(fileMatched) == 0:
            raise NotFoundError, 'File could not be found.'
    except NotFoundError, error:
        print error
```

When I call the function like so:

```
csvPath = findFirstMatch('bounding_box_limits.csv')
```

I get this error message when running in the Python console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MassSpringDamperCAD.py", line 121, in <module>
    main()
  File "MassSpringDamperCAD.py", line 90, in main
    with open(csvPath, 'r') as csvFile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "['.\\\\common\\\\bounding_box_limits.csv']"
```

It found the file, but how did all those extra backslashes end up in the file path?

Note: I am using Windows 7, and Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Where's that string coming from?

Comment: Is that really the code, because you keep setting lastFilename to filename in your loop, then overwrite fileMatched with that. I doin't see how os.path.join is involved in that

Comment: @TomTanner That was a mistake, where I was testing alternative outputs to determine the origin of the quadruple backslashes. I have corrected the code to what it actually was.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I edited the post to contain the full error message and traceback info. The string is returned by `fnmatch.filter()` when it finds an element of `filenames` fitting the criteria of the string argument `targetFile`. I'm sure there's a better way to do this without `fnmatch`, and I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These *backslashes* are side effect of the fact that they're *backslashes*. Gobbledygook :-)

In strings, the backslash to mean backslash is often preceded by backslash in CLI, otherwise in precedes special character synonym, like `\n` for newline, `\t` for tab. From my experience the number of these backslashes does not cause problems. You can always try to normalize the path in string by [`os.path.normpath()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase).

This problem is certainly **Windows** specific.

Comment: Okay, so `os.path.normpath()` worked! The resulting file path still had brackets and excess single quotes attached, which was interfering with interpretation; this became obvious when I tried returning `os.path.abspath(os.path.normpath(filePath))`. I applied `str.strip('[]\'')` to remove them.

Comment: The presence of "[]" in your string returned from function is caused by the fact, that you call `str()` on the array. Call it on `fileMatched[0]`, to make sure that you return one filename, otherwise you may face problem that your string looks like ".\common\bounding_box_limits.csv,.\common\bounding_box_limits.2.csv" after you apply `str.strip('[]\'')`.

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't think I could use that index because I thought it might generate a bunch of empty cells before finding the first file match (I'm still figuring out Python iterator behavior). To compromise, I put `if len(fileMatched) != 0` and the return within that conditional statement; however, it appears I should have indented it to be inside the `for` loop if I wanted the function to return after the first result.